# Create A Variable Number of Children Records

Tags: apex, trigger

Scenario: 3 objects: Account, Opportunity, OpportunityChild. Upon Opportunity create, loop through all Accounts, and for each Account record where Primary = True, create one OpportunityChild record related to that Account.

```
trigger CreateChild on Parent__c (after insert) {

    List<Child__c> Childs = new List<Child__c>();

    for(Parent__c a : trigger.new)
    {
       Child__c Child = new Child__c ();
       Child.Parent__c = a.id;
       Child.Name = 'testName'; 

       Childs.add(Child);      
    }

    insert Childs;
}
```

Comment: Your question still is not very clear. What is the relationship between parent and account?

Comment: OK, updated again using: Account, Opportunity, OpportunityChild

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your requirement correctly then this might be the solution you are looking for,

```
trigger CreateChild on Parent__c (after insert) {

    // Child record list to insert
    List<Child__c> childList = new List<Child__c>();

    // Instance variable to hold multipule child records
    Child__c child;
    Integer count = 0;

    // Loop through all parent records
    for(Parent__c a : trigger.new) {

        // Ignore all the parent records
        // where your condition is not satisfied
        if(false == a.Your_CheckBox__c) {
            continue;

        } else {
            ++count;
            child = new Child__c ();
            child.Parent__c = a.Id;
            child.Name = 'testName ' + count 
            childList.add(Child);
        }
    }
    insert childList;
}
```

Comment: OP's question is bit confusing but your code works like this: If there are 10 parents inserted in one transaction and all the 10 objects have that checkbox selected then it creates one child object for each parent object but they will be named, test name 1, test name 2 and test name 3 and so on..

Comment: Yeah, I appended that number just to keep names non-duplicating. Thanks

Comment: Yes my question probably was not worded well. 3 objects, Account, Parent, Child. Child has a basic lookup to Account. Upon Parent create, loop through all Accounts, and for each Account record where Primary = True, create one Child record related to that Account

Comment: @TNSalesforceGuru There you go..I was skeptical, looking at the question..You should edit the question to be clear. and what is the relation between Account and Parent object?